connect to linked service in Azure Data factory using robot framework
how to connect to linked service in Azure Data Factory and run a query there using robot framework

Maybe you are looking for the Database Library: https://marketsquare.github.io/Robotframework-Database-Library/? Not possible to help without looking at your code or what you have tried so far.

Thanks Pramesh for your reply, I am trying to connect to Azure data factory and there is a linked service inside that from there i need to run the postgresql query, some info regarding the same.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-linked-services?tabs=data-factory
